# Conflict solution required in jQuery and $ in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, simpletip

I have two pages with a script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {      
    jQuery("#"+id).simpletip({
    /*content: 'A simple tooltip2 A simple tooltip2 A simple tooltip2',*/                       
        content: msg,
        fixed: true,        
        position: ["0", positionVal]        

    });
});
```

but i have one problem, one page is working using above method but another page is working only when i replace **jQuery** with **$**. is there any alternative by which I can solve this conflict?

I tried jQuery.noConflict(); and var j = jQuery.noConflict(); method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check for other lib, like prototype, which might set the variable too.

Comment: is there any method in javascript by which i can find, if abc.com/test1/* is calling the function then include one method otherwise second method.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you're asking, but sounds like a wrong concept. You should rather use the canonical name... or find what's using $ and if there's something, use canonical name for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have other library there. You can however use `$` on both of your pages like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  // use $ now
});
```

Or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
   // use $ now
});
```

FYI, you can also check what `$` resolves to using:

```
alert($); // or console.log($)
```

Comment: thanks, but it is doing same thing as **jQuery** does, and not working in case of **$**